# Select a column only if id is distinct MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
  AMAZON_ID  |    DATE    |  STATUS
   1         | 01/03/2014 |  Pending
   1         | 01/03/2014 |  Shipped
   2         | 01/04/2014 |  Pending
   3         | 01/05/2014 |  Cancelled
   4         | 01/06/2014 |  Pending
```

How can I select the earliest date from table where status is equals Pending where the count of id is not more then one, it should be like the following:

```
  AMAZON_ID  |    DATE    |  STATUS
   2         | 01/04/2014 |  Pending
```

I can not figure that out, this is what I have so far but its not working:

```
SELECT date
FROM table
WHERE status = 'Pending'
      AND COUNT(id) < 2
ORDER BY date ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I'm gonna try and come up with a real answer for you, but typically "ID" columns are set as PK's and unique, meaning you can't insert a value that already exists.

Comment: I didn't set that as primary, it must be not unique

Comment: Why can't your ID's be unique? That's what an ID is by its very nature.

Comment: Because its an import from a CSV file which have to be uploaded with same id twice

Comment: That sounds like a problem that needs to be fixed at the root instead of trying to work around it with some clever sql.

Comment: I agree with @Zarazthuztra. Instead of having multiple records with the same ID, you could make another table for transaction status updates.

Comment: No, we did that special because we want to see the history of the orders

Comment: The fact that the column is called `ID` is irrelevant.  Think of it as `orderID` and pretend (if you want) that there's a real PK `id` column.  The OP wants the earliest order record that is still pending.

Comment: A unique id in addition to your order id number wouldn't preclude you from showing order history

Comment: @Patrick Q The column is not called ID its actually called with another name lets change it

Comment: @believeme My comment was directed at the other commenters, not you  :)

Comment: @PatrickQ orderID would need to be unique as well. Figure out the orders that are still pending beyond or before a certain date has nothing to do with ID's

Comment: @Zarazthuztra orderID would not need to be unique if this is some sort of `OrderStatusHistory` table

Comment: @PatrickQ Then the DB needs to be designed around that. If you're marking anything as an identifier of any shape or sort, it needs to be unique, or uniquely identifiable in some way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a subquery to `GROUP BY` the `id`'s that have `COUNT` of 1.  Make sure your id is `IN` the results of this subquery, with a `status` of pending.  Then `ORDER BY` date and `LIMIT` to the first result.

```
SELECT date
FROM table
WHERE
  status = 'Pending' AND
  id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM table
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
  )
ORDER BY date ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying something similar but didn't think of the IN function.

Comment: I didn't dv, but using IN() like this is pretty ugly!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is use a WHERE IN, and use a select statement to populate the WHERE clause with distinct ids

```
 SELECT date
            FROM table
            WHERE status = 'Pending'
            AND id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table)
            ORDER BY date ASC
            LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This would return every `id`. OP wants id's that only have 1 row in the table.

Comment: Downvote care to explain? This accomplishes the task at hand in a much smaller and more efficient method, unless I'm grossly mistaken on what OP is trying to do. DISTINCT will filter out the duplicate ID's for you, no need for complex SQL logic like HAVING COUNT

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you really mean by *"count of id is not more than one"*.

I have renamed your column *date* to *ts* to make the queries valid SQL (as DATE is a SQL function so it may confuse parsers). See the [SQL fiddle for the complete schema I used and the example queries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95ec8/11).

## Option 2: one row per ID *total*

In this case you have a problem because you want a query to get one piece of information (the minimum date) that is based on a different piece of information about the same table. This means that you need to queries, luckily you can just join the data of the two queries and filter appropriately.

```
SELECT data.id, status, MIN(ts)
FROM data
    JOIN (SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS amount FROM data GROUP BY id) AS totals
     ON totals.id = data.id
WHERE
    status = "Pending"
    AND totals.amount < 2
GROUP BY data.status;
```

## <strike>Option 1 (easy): only one *pending* row per ID</strike>

**NOTE**: this answer does not answer the OP's question

<strike>In this case, the situation is quite easy as you can just filter all your rows with status *"pending"*, the minimum date and the total amount of rows that match your result and, after the aggregation (i.e.: using *HAVING*) filter those that have less than 2 amounts.</strike>

In SQL that would be:

```
SELECT id, status, MIN(ts) AS minTS, COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM data
WHERE
    status = "Pending"
GROUP BY id, status
HAVING amount < 2
```

Comment: That is not what I want to do, I want to execute just one row, check out the question again.

Comment: you are right, my bad but you can correct my queries by changing the GROUP BY to data.status